# How to display free space in percentage using whole numbers

Tags: linux, shell

```
Use%
  0%
  0%
  2%
  0%
 12%
  6%
  0%
```

Above I have the percentages of free space I want a command that will only show one of these percentages
I want the output to look like this below

```
12%
```

Comment: Where did you get the data? It may affect the answer.

Comment: Should it always be the 6th row?

Comment: "I want a command that will only show one of these percentages" -> This is very vague. If a choose a command that will always show you the second of them, would you be satisfied? I guess not. Please [edit] the question and clarify your intent, and also show us the command you run to get that output (`df | awk '{print $5}'`?)

Comment: Do you mean only print lines which are greater than 0%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it: `Whatever_the_command | head --lines=6 | tail --line=1`

Comment: what does whatever the command mean

Comment: You have to replace it with the command. The one that produced the output. The one that you did not tell us what it was. The one that I asked you what it was.